# Django server is not restarting

Tags: django, pycharm

I'm using Django and after committing new edits I need to restart my server to see them.
But every time after restart with `python manage.py runserver` my server is not loading I need to use another port to see my website

I`m using Pycharm and Debian terminal

I tried to reboot my pc and it helped but only for 1 time, I mean I can start my server by a default port but can't restart him again with the same port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem and solution for this
All what you need its just to release your port with this command:

```
sudo fuser -k 8000/tcp
```

Answer (score 0):

you can run this command:

`lsof -i:<portnumber>`

To see if the port is being used, and what is using it.